# Permissions are not taking effect with Kerberised NFSv4 on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, nfs, kerberos, nfs4

I'm currently trying to set up an NFSv4 server on FreeBSD. I have extensive experience with doing this on other Unices (Solaris and Linux), but I'm fairly new to FreeBSD.

My goal is to achieve the following:

- Files served from the FreeBSD system
- The only security model should be **krb5p**
- Clients are Linux (Ubuntu) and OSX

Currently, I have managed to set things up so that I need a valid TGT in order to access the file system. After an attempt to access those files, I can run `klist` on the client and I can see that the `nfs/domainname` principal has been retrieved. This suggests that the Kerberos part of the NFS mount is correct.

**My problem is that all client accesses are still performed using the `nobody` user.** I can see the permissions when I do `ls -l`. Even the user mapping works correctly, but unless `nobody` has permission to do anything with the files, I get a permission denied.

Here's an example interaction from the client (Ubuntu in this case, but the same thing happens from OSX). In this example, `/export/shared/testshare` is the shared directory from the FreeBSD server:

(I have changed the actual domain name to `domain` and the Kerberos realm name to `REALM`)

```
$ kinit
Password for elias@REALM:
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000_GBjtDP
Default principal: elias@REALM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/02/2013 09:40:47  10/02/2013 09:40:44  krbtgt/REALM@REALM
$ sudo mount -t nfs4 -osec=krb5p,vers=4 lion:/export/shared/testshare /mnt
$ ls -l /mnt
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup   5 Feb  7 18:17 bar.txt
-rw------- 1 elias  nogroup   4 Feb  5 23:09 foo.txt
$ cat /mnt/bar.txt
blah
$ echo foo >>/mnt/bar.txt
bash: /mnt/bar.txt: Permission denied
$ cat /mnt/foo.txt
cat: /mnt/foo.txt: Permission denied
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000_GBjtDP
Default principal: elias@REALM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/02/2013 09:40:47  10/02/2013 09:40:44  krbtgt/REALM@REALM
09/02/2013 09:41:56  10/02/2013 09:40:44  nfs/lion.domain@REALM
```

**Server configuration**

I have had quite some problems in finding a comprehensive guide to setting up NFSv4 on FreeBSD. This is somewhat surprising in itself as I have found that information on how to do things in FreeBSD to be very good.

Here are the relevant lines in `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
rpcbind_enable="YES"
nfs_server_enable="YES"
nfsv4_server_enable="YES"
nfsuserd_enable="YES"
nfscbd_enable="YES"
mountd_enable="YES"
gssd_enable="YES"
rpc_lockd_enable="YES"
rpc_statd_enable="YES"
zfs_enable="YES"
```

Here is the content of `/etc/exports`:

```
/export/shared/testshare -sec=krb5p
V4: / -sec=krb5p
```

Another interesting aspect is that when I used `tcpdump` to record the NFS network traffic between the client and the server, I saw **NFS3** packets together with the **NFS4** packets. Both of these packet types contained encrypted data, so I still think Kerberos was used, but given the configuration above, I would have expected there to be nothing but NFS4 traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. After going through the code I found that the cause was a bug in the GSS library. The problem was caused by a buffer sent to `getpwnam_r` that was too small.

All the details can be found in the discussion on the [mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2013-February/039861.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to disable nfs3 with `vfs.nfsd.server_min_nfsvers=4`.
2. To avoid "nobody", NFSv4 client and server should be in the same <strike>domain</strike> realm.

Comment: I did number 1 already, and it had no effect. As for number 2, are you referring to the DNS domain or the Kerberos realm?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "realm". Of course, it shouldn't be necessary but it's been easy when possible. A close second is add them to "Local-Realms" in the idmapd.conf.

Comment: They are both in the same realm though (and the same domain).

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, there has to be some way to map usernames between the systems. Are you running idmapd on both server and client? Ldap?

At least as a test, try making specific mappings between names ... other than root, at least initially.

Comment: The mapping works. I get the correct user names displayed. However, the actual permissions that are being applied are for "nobody".

Comment: So, everything's working but it still fails. Sorry I couldn't really help.